# How do i add an icon to my Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, icons

So I made a game on unity and i would like to add an icon to the game, so that a desktop icon in custom made. I tried looking it up in google, but i can't seem to find the answer, as all the answers that are given are for something else.

Comment: how do i TICK the answer, I am quite new to StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On player settings, check the inspector, one of those tabs says "Icon" check the " override for Standalone" and simply select the icon you want.

[image: File then build settings]

[image: Player settings]

[image: Inspector and Icon]

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda late but oh well. Found a helpful video on YouTube: Import the icon you want into the assets as a picture format (.jpg .png whatever etc) and when you go to build your game, click and drag the icon you imported over the box next to "Default icon". I did that with mine and it worked, no need to check "Override for standalone" (I don't even know what that does) Note: I did this on Unity 2020.1.0f1 Personal.

Sauce: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcwxWWRPwLA