# Despite putting an image in the Default Icon section, that image is not coming as my game's icon. What should I do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have placed an Image of my liking in the Default Icon section of [General Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html). It is still not changing my game's icon. I followed the procedure from [How do i add an icon to my Unity Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422993/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-my-unity-game) but it did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i add an icon to my Unity Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422993/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-my-unity-game)

Comment: I followed that exact procedure before posting the question and still got no results.

Comment: What Unity version? Are you sure you did that for the desired platform?

Comment: Its Unity 2018.3.0f2
And yes, the desired platform is PC, Mac and Linus Standalone and did the above for that platform itself

Comment: And how did you build the game? Did you uncheck "developement build" ? Are you overwriting the build or put it in a new folder? Have you tried restarting? Maybe windows has the icon cached? Try to rename the application in Unity to make sure.

Comment: By unchecking "development build", I'm not being able to build my visual studio solution. With that option checked, the app is working just fine. I'm overwriting the build. I have tried restarting, but it did not help. I tried using the same icon that I had used for a different game that I had built earlier. The icon had worked for that app. So I figured that it would work for this one as well, but it didn't.